# Website security hole

Tags: php, security

I have a website, im using sessions for the login. In every pages of my admin, I have a checker if the user has logged in or not. I have this code

```
if(!$_SESSION['loggedin'] && !$_SESSION['userid'])
{
  header('Location:login.php');
}
else
{
 //proceed loading the page
}
```

Now what happen now, someone is messing up with our site. He/She is entering some vulgar texts on the website like ... All disrespectful words and its so frustrating because the website is accessible to the public.
I believe the username and password was being hacked. So i asked all admin users to changed all passwords and i added a logger to monitor who will update the content of the website. I record the userid of the logged in user and its post. After changing passwords, the same thing happen again, content was updated by the hacker or whoever he is.

I checked my log, the user id of the hacker is 0. How is that possible and how do i stop him? Makes me wonder what did he do because it is in my condition at the very top of the page that if $_SESSION['userid'] has no value, it should redirect them to the login page.

Currently i put the website offline because the hacker is getting worst and worst. I was able to find out the ip address of it.

This is my user authentication

```
$user=trim($_POST['username']);
$pass=trim(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if( mysql_num_rows($qry) )
{
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
  $_SESSION['userid'] =$row['userid'];
  $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;  
  header('Location: welcome.php');
}
else
{
      header('Location:login.php?error=1');
}
```

Comment: Show how your website authenticates user. It seems that you got SQL injection.

Comment: Hi nhahtdh, I updated my question above. I showed the script on how do i authenticate user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nhahtdh observed, you have an obvious SQL injection. Consider what happens if someone where to enter `admin' OR 1=1; --` into your username field (yes, people do indeed try these sorts of things). Your SQL string gets converted into something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='admin' OR 1=1; -- AND pass='junk'
```

Which will select all of the users from your user table. The `userid` of 0 is, presumably, the first `userid` in your SQL table.

Please have a look [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/274466) that explains how to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Hi, i tried inputting admin' OR 1=1; --  in the username box and submit the form. I got a sql synthax error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' AND pass='' at line 1

Comment: @user1149244: Sorry, yes, there should be a space after the two dashes `--`. so you end up with "`admin' or 1=1; -- `". Note that it if your page displays that SQL error, that is also a serious security concern. That may be how the hacker figured out how to hack your site in the first place.

Comment: You are right, was able to login with this admin' or 1=1; -- " ... omg.. this is scary.

Comment: A better technique 1. Retrieve the record where user='$user' and nothing else. Then compare in PHP the retrieved password with the $_POSTed password.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to always call [exit](http://php.net/exit) after a `Header('Location: ...')` call. Otherwise the script will continue execution after the header call. it will continue as far as sending everything after the `header` call to the browser, but regular browsers will see the location header and do a redirect. Not-so-nice users may circumvent the location call and can surf your "protected" page as they wish!

So, don't forget to *always*  end execution immediately:

```
header('Location:login.php');
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you Emil, i'll do this.